# Laravel 4.2 Class 'Form' not found

Tags: forms, laravel-4

I have looked and looked and looked and can find no solutions to this problem. There are solutions for Laravel 5 but I don't think they apply to Laravel 4. Anyone know of the easiest way to get rid of this?

This is the code that causes the problem:

```
{{Form::open}}
```

Comment: Looks like your post is missing the form/code in question...?

Comment: I included the simplest Form:: example I could find. The point being that the Form class is not found. I guess it needs to be pointed to somewhere.

Comment: 4 spaces in front of a line formats it to make clear it's code. It looked at first sight that you messed up a link, but it appears Form::open _is_ the code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `illuminate/html` in `composer.json`

also remember to register the 
service provider : `Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider`

and to add the aliases : `'HTML' => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade'`

```
'Form' => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade'
```

for more information [Click here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/43-forms)

Comment: This partially solved the problem. The Html folder did not exists. I downloaded it from GitHub and everything is fine